# background image disappeared in Chrome after scrolling down

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have set a image which has a resolution of 1980 x 1200 as background for the web page. When I scrolled down (I think after the height of 1200 px) the image just dissappears and white color background appears. This happens only in Chrome, in safari it works perfect. Here's what I've used in CSS

```
body,html{
margin-top: 0px;
background-image: url(../_images/1902974.jpg);

background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center top;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

I have also tried background-position:fixed  but it doesn't work only on Chrome. 
Do I need to add any code?

Comment: I had used a Table in the web page. I've set the width of the table to 960px as my content wrapper's size. When I removed the table the background image works fine. If I used the table, the image dissappears after 1200px

Answer (score 4):

Simple way for a full screen background. (The BG image does not scroll like this). If you want it to scroll then set `fixed` to `scroll`.

**CSS**

```
html { 
  background: url(images/mybgimage.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-attachment: fixed; /* Or scroll */
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**Works in:**

1. Safari 3+
2. Chrome Whatever+
3. IE 9+
4. Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)
5. Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)

Answered based from [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Comment: I had used a Table in the web page. I've set the width of the table to 960px as my content wrapper's size. When I removed the table the background image works fine. If I used the table, the image dissappears after 1200px

Comment: @Anbu If that is a vital detail then it should have been mentioned in your post. Any specific details related to the problem should be stated. All relevant code should be posted.

Answer (score 0):

try adding minimum height to hundred percent to html and body
and background-size property to cover

Comment: still the image dissappears. One thing i did was I set the min height to 2000px. Now I scrolled down the page, after 1200px the image dissappears. And I scrolled down further, at some point the image appears again. Then i scrolled up to the 1200 px the image dissappears once again

Comment: have you added background-repeat property to no repeat and thn set min-height to 2000px?

Comment: yeah. butsame thing happens image dissappears after 1200px and i scrolled further down, the image appears now

Answer (score 0):

Many way to achieve this but you can try:

```css
body,html{
background-image: url(../_images/1902974.jpg);
background-size:cover
}
```

Comment: Can you give the code, mostly the jpg you are using. Maybe this: body,html{
positiont: absolute;
top:0px;left:0px
}